# How do I ask a question in the Facebook help center?

Tags: facebook

I can't find a method to do so!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Go to the [Facebook Help Center](http://www.facebook.com/help/)
2. Click on ["Help Discussions"](http://www.facebook.com/help/?section=community) on the left sidebar.
   It should be the third link.
   [image: Help Discussion Topics]
3. Then click on the topic that you want to ask a question about and then the subtopic.
   [image: Home and News Feed Topic]
4. Only then, you'll find an option to ask a new question.
   [image: Ask a Question]

Comment: There is no option to ask a question on that link. I am having the same problem here, I have looked EVERYWHERE

Comment: @Amanda Check the pictures above, it should be easier now.

Comment: What's most amusing about having found my way here is that I need to ask another site about how to ask Facebook for help on their site...