# Facebook - ask three friends to confirm your account

Tags: facebook, account-recovery

I'm in a very stupid situation. I'm not much into social networks and I have tried to created and account on Facebook three times over these years. Every time I end up blocked without a way to recover my account (The last time I was unable to recover using my phone because I used wrong phone format).

This is my third account. Facebook is asking me to get confirmation from three friends. But In fact, from the suggested list I can call only one person. Facebook isn't giving me any other options to recover my account.

Do I have any other options to get my account back, or I should just give up and register a new one?

Comment: How do I ask a question in the Facebook help center? -[https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7978/45867

Comment: @bummi I'm sorry, but did you check the link yourself before posting it? This is so out of date! I've spent an hour and a half of my life for clicking all possible links and reading docs to do something as simple as logging into facebook. I've already have google to give me thousands of links to read, thank you so much. PS Also thank you for downvoting this question withhout a comment to whoever did this.